# automatic git clone using yml file gitlab

Tags: php, git, yaml, gitlab

I am trying to setup automatic git clone/pull on server using gitlab yml file.

How to check git repository exist using yml script, if exist then git pull otherwise make git clone.
I want below output :

```
If GIT REPO NOT EXIST then

   git clone

else

  no action
```

below is my yml file, can anyone help me

```
cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/

before_script:
  - php -v
  - pwd
  - mkdir -p /var/www/html
  - if [ ! -d /var/www/html/.git ] then
  - git clone http://username:password@XX.XX.XX.XXX/root/myproject.git /var/www/html
  - fi

stages:
  - deploy

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to staging server"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://XX.XX.XX.XXX/
  script:
    - cd $webroot
    - git pull
```

Comment: try `scandir` function to check whether folder exists or not ?
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_directory_scandir.asp

Comment: thank @prakash but i want execute check in gitlab YML file script, so if you know about YML file script, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get an "unexpected end of file" error. First, you miss the semicolon of the if, it should go `if [ ! -d ... ]; then`.

If I remember correctly, each command is executed in an own shell.
So GitLab executes:

```
sh -c 'php -v'
sh -c 'pwd'
sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/html'
sh -c 'if [ ! -d /var/www/html/.git ] then'
sh -c 'git clone http://username:password@XX.XX.XX.XXX/root/myproject.git /var/www/html'
sh -c 'fi'
```

The other problem is that the if, git clone, and fi are not connected. So you can either use a multi-line string or use a little shorthand:

```
before_script:
  - php -v
  - pwd
  - mkdir -p /var/www/html
  - [ -d /var/www/html/.git ] || git clone http://username:password@XX.XX.XX.XXX/root/myproject.git /var/www/html
```

This says: If the directory check fails (`[ -d` fails when it can not find the directory), execute the `git clone`. The `||` operator is what shell executes if the command fails, the `&&` operator is what it executes when the command succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i want to execute command using gitlab CI YML file, and you have mention sh command, so this is not working with gitlab yml command.

Comment: @Girish Patidar It does as long as GitLab calls sh which was what I meant.